# Bounding spot-checking sublinear algorithm candidate for detecting a sorted array

Tags: probability-theory, algorithms

The source to the piece of an abstract listed below: [Sublinear algorithms](https://sublinear-course.wikispaces.com/file/view/lecture2.pdf).

So I have a homework assignment connected to bounding the amount of array accessings of a sublinear algo that tries to guess whether the input array is sorted or not.

Here is a piece of an abstract I can't make sense of:

---

**Input**: a list $x_1,...,x_n$ of arbitrary numbers

**Goal**: an $\epsilon$-tester for sortedness (monotonicity) of the list with running time $O({logn \over \epsilon})$

**Testers that do not work**:

1. ..
2. Proposed test: Pick random $i<j$ and reject if $x_i>x_j$.
   Counterexample:
   $$1~\color{blue}0~2~\color{blue}1~3~\color{blue}2~4~\color{blue}3~5~\color{blue}4~6~\color{blue}5$$
   The Hamming distance of this list to the property "sortedness" is $\geq {1 \over 2}$ because for each black/blue consecutive pair ((1,0), (2,1). etc.) at least one of the two numbers has to be changed to make the first list sorted. *But* any other pair is correctly ordered. This implies, by Birthday Paradox, that we need to select $s=\Omega(\sqrt(n))$ numbers to find a pair of numbers that is out of order with probability $\geq {2 \over 3}$.

---

So what I can't understand is an application of a Birthday Paradox in this case as well as interconnection of $\epsilon$ with an amount of times the sampling of a pair $i,j$ should be done. Here is some additional information toghether with my thoughts:

So Hamming distance in this case is expressed as $\epsilon n$, where $n$ is an amount of items in an input array and $\epsilon \in (0,1]$. Together it indicates an amount of modifications that we are "tolerating" assuming that the input array is sorted if it less then $\epsilon n$-far from the totally sorted array.

Given the "worst-case" input from the above, the probability of sampling a pair of $i,j$ that would allow the algorithm to determine that the input array is not sorted is:

$$P(return~"not~sorted")~=~ {n \over 2 {\binom n2}} = {1 \over {n-1}}$$

The intuition behind the above formula is that we have exactly ${n \over 2}$ pair that would allow us to determine that array is not sorted and in total there are $\binom n2$ possible pairs from the $n$ items in the array.

Multiplying the above probability with an amount of iteration of sampling $i,j$ (denoting it $k$) I got the lower bound on $k$ of getting an error (returning sorted for an above obviously unsorted array) with probability at most ${2 \over 3}$:

$$k \geq {{2(n-1)} \over 3}$$

The property ${{2(n-1)} \over 3} = \Omega(\sqrt n)$ seems to hold. But what can I do with Birthday Paradox and how does $\epsilon$ influence the $k$?

Help is appreciated! (hope the problem statement is understandable)

Comment: FYI: your link points to your home directory (which, of course, cannot be accessed remotely).

Comment: @ClementC. forgot I'm viewing it locally. Fixed it now. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: You're welcome. Also, I have updated my answer -- let me know if i forgot to adress some of your questions.

Comment: @ClementC. Thanks a lot. I need some time to read through your answer. I'll let you know if I still have some issues with understanding, otherwise, I'll accept the answer.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all: in this counterexample, $\varepsilon$ is set to be a constant, namely $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. The goal here is to show that the proposed tester has a bad dependence on the main parameter, $n$, without bothering about the dependence on $\varepsilon$ for now.
- Then, to see why the Birthday paradox box up: you have $\frac{n}{2}$ "slots" $B_1,\dots, B_{n/2}$ of consecutive elements, where $B_k=\{a_{2i-1}, a_{2i}\}$. To detect a violation, you need to sample two elements in the same slot (as two elements $x,y$ from different slots will not give you any violation of sortenedness: if $x \in B_k$ and $y\in B_\ell$ with $k < \ell$, then $x\leq y$).

  So, when sampling two elements $i,j$ independently and uniformly at random and checking if the pair $(i,j)$ is a violation,you need that both $i$ and $j$ fall in the same $B_k$. This is where the Birthday paradox pops in:

  > To get at least two people out of $m$ having their birthday on the same day (out of $\frac{n}{2}$ days, assuming everyone's birthday is independently and uniformly chosen among the $n/2$ days), you need $m=\Omega(\sqrt{n})$.

  Another intuitive view is that the probability that two distinct indices $(i,j)$ with $i< j$ end up in the same block $B_k$ is $p_{i,j} = \frac{1}{n/2} = \frac{1}{n-1}$. By linearity of expectation, if you take $m$ indices uniformly at random (and thus have $\binom{m}{2}$ such pairs), the expected number of collisions you will see is 
  $$
  \binom{m}{2}\cdot \frac{2}{n} = \frac{m(m-1)}{n} \leq \frac{m^2}{n}
  $$
  so you need $m=\Omega(\sqrt{n})$ samples to (on expectation) see at least one such collision (and be able to detect unsortedness).
- If you are concerned about the dependence on $\varepsilon$: you will see later a "good" tester for this property with query complexity $O\left(\frac{\log n}{\varepsilon}\right)$, which can be show to be necessary. Moreover, it is not hard to see that for any "reasonable" property (sortedness is one), you will need $\Omega(1/\varepsilon)$ no matter what you do (the idea being: if you take less than that, you will not "hit" any bad point, that is the ones contradicting the property).

As another reference, you can check [these lecture notes](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~rocco/Teaching/S14/Scribe/scribe.html), e.g. Section 1.2 (p.6) for sortenedness. *(Disclaimer: these are by my adviser.)*

Comment: I have a concern about the probability of choosing a pair of (i, j). As I understand, the amount of available j's depends on chosen i. Therefore is it correct to choose only from pairs that are next to each other (then the answer is n/2)? What if i=2 and j=5? Moreover, if chosen u.a.r i is even then no matter what j will be chosen the algo won't be able to detect a violation. Is it possible to calculate this probability assuming roll of i and j as two separate events?

Comment: Look at it differently: picking a pair $(i,j)$ such that $i<j$ is exactly the same as picking a pair $(i',j')$ with $i'\neq j'$ and reordering it if needed. The probability of collision (falling in the same $B_k$) will not change. Technically, picking $i$ and $j$ are not independent, as you don't want $i=j$, but that is pretty much the same otherwise. (If that is too handwavy, I'll update my answer whenever I get a chance.)

Comment: I tried to do it in the following way: we have $\binom n2$ possible pairs of $(i,j)$. And there are only $n/2$ pairs that are representing each of the $B_k$. Then the probability of rolling a needed pair is ${n \over {2 \binom n2}}={1 \over {n-1}}$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Where in the argument are you using this? This is indeed correct -- my argument above ignored (i) order and (ii) distinctness of $i,j$, so the $p_{i,j} = \frac{2}{n}$ should be $\frac{1}{n-1}$.

Comment: I'm not trying to argue or someting. I'm just eager to understand the whole math behind the abstract from the source I gave above. Thank you for your help! 

One last question: how can I express the exact dependence (in formula) of $k$ from $\epsilon$? (I need it to bound an amount of iterations of an algo given $k$ and $\epsilon$ as an input to it).

Comment: No, I'm not saying asking questions is a bad thing, mostly trying to answer the right points :) So for the $\varepsilon$, in short: you cannot with this. There is no $\varepsilon$ in the example (or, more accurately, you have $\varepsilon = 1/2$, it's not a variable anymore). The distance of your "bad instance for the proposed test" to sortedness is $\frac{1}{2}n$, so what is shown is that even for "big" values of $\varepsilon$, up to $\varepsilon=1/2$, this particular tester must have query complexity $\Omega(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: If you want to quantify the exact query complexity of this particular tester (as a function of $n,\varepsilon$), for the lower bound you cannot use this particular construction of "bad instance," you will need to modify it to get distance $\varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon$ is any value given to you, of $1/2$ instead (so that $\varepsilon$ is "in the picture). (does that make sense?)

Comment: Glad this helped :)